# Emacs Live - Namespace not found

Tags: emacs, clojure

I'm using [Emacs Live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live) because it seemed nice and saves me a lot of configuration work. Now it worked fine for a few days, but today something apparently broke. Specifically, auto completion broke (I believe it might be an issue with [ac-nrepl](https://github.com/purcell/ac-nrepl)). Basically, my minibuffer now only shows "Namespace not found.", I don't get real auto-completion anymore (only completion on words that are already in the file). And when I run `C-c M-n` I get an empty *nREPL error* buffer every time auto completion would usually kick in.

EDIT: This *only* happens when I start an nrepl-server with nrepl-jack-in. Just connecting to an existing one (e.g. created with lein repl) works fine.

Comment: if you make a new test project with lein new does it work in that new project? This may help decide if it is a project configuration/structure problem or an emacs problem.

Comment: Same thing happens with a completely blank project.

Comment: Ask the fine folks on #clojure at irc.freenode.net

Comment: I'd rather not. I do frequent #clojure, but the last time I asked an emacs question there was a short but unnecessary flamewar on whether or not emacs should be used with preconfigured packages. It also feels sort of off topic since it isn't directly related to clojure (except if it was a bug with nrepl itself, which I doubt)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue with `Namespace not found` is that the nrepl doesn't know about the namespace of the current buffer. The issue with nrepl-set-ns (`C-c M-n`) is that is running `in-ns`, which doesn't bring the clojure core dependencies.

In both cases, the work around is to either eval just the `ns` s-expr of the buffer or to load the whole buffer with `nrepl-load-current-buffer`.

Of course you can modify the nrepl-set-ns to do a `ns` or add another fn.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding a possibly empty ns declaration to the buffer:

```
(ns example ...)
```

and performing `nrepl-set-ns` is nrepl's intended usage. It allows working with multiple Clojure buffers, each with its own imports, aliases etc.

I've opted for adding a hook to `.clj` file creation/opening which automates this work. One still is responsible for refreshing the `ns` form on modification, though!